# SQLite Query decimal places

Tags: sqlite, decimal

I have a SQLite database, and I need to extract some values from DB.
I use next query to do it:

```
SELECT 
   date, code, model, price,
   SUM(Units),SUM(Total)
   FROM VTA_VTAdetalle 
   where code = '07' 
   GROUP BY date, 
            code, 
            price 
   ORDER BY date ASC
```

[image: Query Result]

All is OK with the query, but I can't make it to display 3 decimal places.
I have used round(value,3), but when sum has 0 at right (1.100) it only displays 1.1. What I need is that all the time display 1.100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

printf("%.3f", value) should work for you

Comment: there is no option to add a thouthands separator using SQLite formatting features, so you would have to manipulate data yourself in the query. I think it would be better to handle it in you client code